# How can I automatically jump to the viewport of a newly opened application?

Tags: unity, compiz, workspaces, window-manager, viewports

I have recently discovered the magic of Compiz, which I have now setup to open several applications in different workspaces. My question is how to I get the workspace switcher to automatically jump to the workspace of the app once I open it?

An example of this would be I have file manager open in workspace 2-1 where I click on a movie file, which would open up VLC in workspace 1-2. How do I get the workspace navigator to switch automatically to the VLC in workspace 1-2?

Comment: Would you mind a tiny background script, jumping to the (any) new window?

Comment: @JacobVlijm i would not mind, so long as it doesnt take up much memory or have adverse effects on other running apps.

Comment: ...Practically none!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script below will change the current viewport to the one where *any* new window appears.

The script does not add *any* noticeable/measureable burden (using system monitor) to your system.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import time

def get_wlist():
    # get the output of wmctrl -lG, try because wmctrl is a bit buggy :)
    try:
        return subprocess.check_output(["wmctrl", "-lG"]).decode("utf-8").strip()
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        pass

def get_wids(currlist):
    # get the window ids
    return [l.split()[0] for l in currlist.splitlines()]

def get_abspos():
    posdate = subprocess.check_output(["wmctrl", "-d"]).decode("utf-8").split()
    return [int(n) for n in posdate[5].split(",")]

while True:
    # wait until the desktop is ready to run wmctrl
    wdata1 = get_wlist()
    if wdata1:
        break
    time.sleep(1)

# and then...
wlist1 = get_wids(wdata1)

while True:
    time.sleep(2)
    wdata2 = get_wlist()
    if wdata2:
        wlist2 = get_wids(wdata2)
        new = [w for w in wlist2 if not w in wlist1]
        for item in new:
            line = wdata2.splitlines()[wlist2.index(item)].split()
            pos = [int(line[n]) for n in [2, 3]]
            absposcount = get_abspos()
            abspos = [str(pos[0]+absposcount[0]), str(pos[1]+absposcount[1])]
            # print(abspos)
            subprocess.Popen(["wmctrl", "-o", ",".join(abspos)])
        wlist1 = wlist2; wdata1 = wdata2
```

#### How to use

1. The script needs `wmctrl`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install wmctrl
   ```
2. Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `move_toviewport.py`
3. Run it by the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/move_toviewport.py
   ```
4. If all works fine, add to Startup Applications: Dash > Startup Applications > Add. Add the command above.

#### How it works

- The script keeps an eye on possibly newly appearing windows, using `wmctrl -lG`
- If there is a new window, the script will read its (absolute) position on the spanning workspace, and subsequently move to the corresponding viewport using `wmctrl -o x,y`

Comment: works like a charm! I will award you the bounty when possible.Thanks so much !

Comment: @KalamalkaKid I always love this kind of questions :), I am surprised I missed it!